# Strapi error: column specified more than once

Tags: strapi

I created a content type with an integer field that i named "ID". On save Strapi wouldn't restart via web gui and when I tried to restart with yarn develop I get this: error: column "id" specified more than once. After some searching on google I found that this is a known bug.

How can i fix this when I cant access admin panel? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into the model config settings in `api/yourModel/models/yourModel.settings.json` and delete the ID field you added

Comment: UPDATE 2022: `api/yourModel/content-types/yourModel/schema.json`